# Django model primary key as a pair

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to make an app where users will login to their profile and can add songs to their favorite list. I am defining a M2M relationship for this.

My question is how to say combination of (song, singer) is unique? 
I searched and found that it may be possible through unique_together. Is this the correct way of setting this?

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Singer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name


class Song(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=False)
   singer = models.ForeignKey(Singer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='song')
   name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

   Class Meta:
       unique_together = (singer, id)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song,  related_name='profile')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Please feel free to correct my models.py, if you think the relationship is not correct.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a default primary key (auto field), and use the meta class property, unique_together

```
   class Song(models.Model):
       singer = models.ForeignKey(Singer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='song')
       name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

        class Meta:
            unique_together = (("singer", "name"),)
```

It would act as a "surrogate" primary key column.

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify id in your model song. I would also recommend to use slug field of django and specify unique on the same. Just in case you have two singers with the same name. Then the second or more  you put like abc, abc-1, abc-2, in which case you don't have to change the name and unique_together clause works just fine.

```
class Song(models.Model):
   singer = models.ForeignKey(Singer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='song')
   name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

   class Meta:
       unique_together = (("singer", "name"),)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```