# How to overwrite `id` as primary key with `timestamp` as primary key in django models?

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I'm building a Django ETL engine that extracts data from GitHub using the enterprise API to gather metrics on internal company collaboration. I've designed some schema that I now realize won't scale due to the PK (primary key) that is automatically set by the ORM. One of the main features of the extraction is to get the `id` of the person that has created a repository, commented on a post, etc.

My initial thought was to let the ORM automatically set the `id` as the `PK` but this won't work as the GET request is going to run once a week and it will raise errors causing the overwriting of the `ID` primary key to fail.

I've done some research and one potential solution is to create a meta class as referenced here: [Django model primary key as a pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972589/django-model-primary-key-as-a-pair)

but I am unsure if creating a few meta classes is going to defeat the entire point of a meta class to begin with.

Here is the schema I have setup for the `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

""" Contruction of tables in MySQL instance """


class Repository(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, primary_key=True)
    repo_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    creation_date = models.CharField(max_length=21, null=True)
    last_updated = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    qty_watchers = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    qty_forks = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    qty_issues = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    main_language = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    repo_size = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Contributor(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(null=False, primary_key=True)
    contributor_cec = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    contribution_qty = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    get_request = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Teams(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class TeamMembers(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(null=False, primary_key=True)
    team_member_cec = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    get_request = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Discussions(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(null=False, primary_key=True)
    login = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    comments = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    updated_at = models.CharField(max_length=21, null=True)
    get_request = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Is there a way to overwrite the `id` field and make the `PK` the `timestamp` field since each time the `GET request` is run that field will be populated with static data that will not change over the lifetime of the app?

Alternatively, is there a way to ditch the multi-table inheritance architecture and go for something different?

The core metrics that I will be extracting away from this are things like `top contributor to repository`, `repository with most commits`, `most replied to comments`. I'd like to be able to run some kind of `filters` on the data so as to extract these metrics out but I know this is heavily reliant upon the schema setup.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The way to set a field as the primary key is

```
field_name = models.FieldType(primary_key=True)
```

Comment: That wasn't the question. The question was how to overwrite the `id` field being the primary key.